# Count all same comma separated value in one column mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 table and there's a column which contains comma separated value and I want to count all same value of that column, here's the sample table:

```
Client table 
ID | Name | Procedure 
1  | Joe  | Samp1,Samp2 
2  | Doe  | Samp1,Samp2,Samp3  
3  | Noe  | Samp1,Samp2

Desire Output 
Summary table ( For Procedure ) 
ID | NAME  | COUNT 
1  | Samp1 |  3 
2  | Samp2 |  3 
3  | Samp3 |  1
```

Now, do you have any idea or suggestion so i can make it happen ? like add new table or is this possible with single query ?

Comment: You should change your table design. Never store multiple values in a single column

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574

Comment: @juergend Thanks for the tip, maybe i should remodel my table.

Comment: @e4c5 thanks for that helpful link!

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT LENGTH(COLUMN) - LENGTH(REPLACE(COLUMN, ',', '')) FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: it counts only the comma separated value but not like what i desired output